# Number to Word Application in C#

Tags: c#, numbers-to-words

I've created a Windows Form Number to Word converter application in C# which converts any number from 0 to 1 million. I would love a review based on efficiency and best practices.

**MainInterface.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NumberToWords
{
    public partial class MainInterface : Form
    {
        private NumberToWordsConverter numberToWordsConverter;

        public MainInterface()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainInterface_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.numberToWordsConverter = new NumberToWordsConverter();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string input = textBox1.Text;
            int numberToConvert;

            if (int.TryParse(input, out numberToConvert))
            {
                if (numberToConvert < 0 || numberToConvert > 1000000)
                {
                    label3.Text = "Invalid range, please enter a number between 0 and 1 million inclusively";
                } else
                {
                    string stringData = this.numberToWordsConverter.convertToString(numberToConvert);
                    label3.Text = stringData;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                label3.Text = "Please enter a valid number";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**NumberToWordsConverter.cs**

```
using System;

namespace NumberToWords
{
    public class NumberToWordsConverter
    {
        private string[] numbers = { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen" };
        private string[] tens = { "", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety" };

        public NumberToWordsConverter()
        {

        }

        public string convertToString(int number)
        {
            char[] digits = number.ToString().ToCharArray();
            string words = null;

            if (number >= 0 && number <= 19)
            {
                words = words + this.numbers[number];
            }
            else if (number >= 20 && number <= 99)
            {
                int firstDigit = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[0]);
                int secondPart = number % 10;

                words = words + this.tens[firstDigit];

                if (secondPart > 0)
                {
                    words = words + " " + convertToString(secondPart);
                }
            }
            else if (number >= 100 && number <= 999)
            {
                int firstDigit = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[0]);
                int secondPart = number % 100;

                words = words + this.numbers[firstDigit] + " hundred";

                if (secondPart > 0)
                {
                    words = words + " and " + convertToString(secondPart);
                }
            }
            else if (number >= 1000 && number <= 19999)
            {
                int firstPart = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[0]);
                if (number >= 10000)
                {
                    string twoDigits = digits[0].ToString() + digits[1].ToString();
                    firstPart = Convert.ToInt16(twoDigits);
                }
                int secondPart = number % 1000;

                words = words + this.numbers[firstPart] + " thousand";

                if (secondPart > 0 && secondPart <= 99)
                {
                    words = words + " and " + convertToString(secondPart);
                } else if (secondPart >= 100)
                {
                    words = words + " " + convertToString(secondPart);
                }
            }
            else if (number >= 20000 && number <= 999999)
            {
                string firstStringPart = Char.GetNumericValue(digits[0]).ToString() + Char.GetNumericValue(digits[1]).ToString();

                if (number >= 100000)
                {
                    firstStringPart = firstStringPart + Char.GetNumericValue(digits[2]).ToString();
                }

                int firstPart = Convert.ToInt16(firstStringPart);
                int secondPart = number - (firstPart * 1000);

                words = words + convertToString(firstPart) + " thousand";

                if (secondPart > 0 && secondPart <= 99)
                {
                    words = words + " and " + convertToString(secondPart);
                } else if (secondPart >= 100)
                {
                    words = words + " " + convertToString(secondPart);
                }

            }
            else if (number == 1000000)
            {
                words = words + "One million";
            }

            return words;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NumberToWordsConverter.convertToString(int number)**

- The validation of he passed number shouldn't be done by the caller of the method but by the class itself. You could signal the range of allowed numbers as `Maximum` and `Minimum` either as properties or as `public readonly` fields.

  If we change the start of the method from

  ```
  public string convertToString(int number)
  {
      char[] digits = number.ToString().ToCharArray();
      string words = null;

      if (number >= 0 && number <= 19)
  ```

  to this

  ```
  public string ConvertToString(int number)
  {

      string words = null;
      if (number < 0)
      {
          number *= -1;
          words = "minus ";
      }

      char[] digits = number.ToString().ToCharArray();

      if (number  <= 19)
  ```

  we can extend the minimum range from `0` to `-1000000`. The validation of the passed number based on this is for you to do.
- Based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing. So `convertToString()` should be named `ConvertToString()`
- Using a `static` method instead of an instance method like mentioned by [Xiaoy312](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23443/xiaoy312) is a have to in this case.
- Adding up strings by using `+` will result each time in creating a new string object because strings are immutable. This can be improved by using a `StringBuilder`. I would change this method to have an additional `StringBuilder` argument which is then called by an overladed `ConvertToNumber()` method like so

  ```
  private static void EnsureNumberIsInRange(int number)
  {
      // to be filled by you
  }
  public static string ConvertToString(int number)
  {
      EnsureNumberIsInRange(number);

      if (number == 0)
      {
          return numbers[number];
      }

      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(1024);
      if (number < 0)
      {
          number *= -1;
          builder.Append("minus ");
      }

      ConvertToString(number, builder);
      return builder.ToString().TrimEnd();
  }
  ```

  By handling the case if the passed in number equals `0` we can use this case in the recursivly called overloaded method as guard clause.

  If we change

  ```
  char[] digits = number.ToString().ToCharArray();
  ```

  to

  ```
  string digits = number.ToString();
  ```

  we remove the call to `ToCharArray()` for saving some memory.

  By extracting the edge cases for `number >= 1000 && number <= 19999` and `number >= 20000 && number <= 999999` to separate `if` statements we can clean this up some more which results in this

  ```
  private static void ConvertToString(int number, StringBuilder builder)
  {
      if (number == 0) { return; }

      if (number <= 19)
      {
          builder.Append(numbers[number]);
          return;
      }

      string digits = number.ToString();

      int firstDigit = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[0]);

      if (number <= 99)
      {
          builder.Append(tens[firstDigit])
                 .Append(" ");

          number = number % 10;

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      if (number <= 999)
      {
          builder.Append(numbers[firstDigit])
                 .Append(" hundred ");

          number = number % 100;

          if (number > 0)
          {
              builder.Append("and ");
          }

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      if (number <= 9999)
      {
          builder.Append(numbers[firstDigit])
                 .Append(" thousand ");

          number = number % 1000;

          if (number > 0 && number <= 99)
          {
              builder.Append("and ");
          }

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      if (number <= 19999)
      {
          int firstPart = firstDigit * 10 + (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[1]);

          builder.Append(numbers[firstPart])
                 .Append(" thousand ");

          number = number % 1000;

          if (number > 0 && number <= 99)
          {
              builder.Append("and ");
          }

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      if (number <= 99999)
      {
          int firstPart = firstDigit * 10 + (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[1]);

          ConvertToString(firstPart, builder);

          builder.Append(" thousand ");

          number = number % 1000;

          if (number > 0 && number <= 99)
          {
              builder.Append("and ");
          }

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      if (number <= 999999)
      {
          int firstPart = firstDigit * 100 + (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[1]) * 10 + (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[2]);

          ConvertToString(firstPart, builder);

          builder.Append(" thousand ");

          number = number % (firstPart * 1000);

          if (number > 0 && number <= 99)
          {
              builder.Append("and ");
          }

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      builder.Append("One million");
  }
  ```

  But we still have some small code duplication here regarding

  ```
  if (number > 0 && number <= 99)
  {
      builder.Append("and ");
  }
  ```

  by extracting this to a method like so

  ```
  private static void AppendAndIfNeeded(int number, StringBuilder builder)
  {
      if (number > 0 && number <= 99)
      {
          builder.Append("and ");
      }
  }
  ```

  leading to this

  ```
  private static void ConvertToString(int number, StringBuilder builder)
  {
      if (number == 0) { return; }

      if (number <= 19)
      {
          builder.Append(numbers[number]);
          return;
      }

      string digits = number.ToString();

      int firstDigit = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[0]);

      if (number <= 99)
      {
          builder.Append(tens[firstDigit])
                 .Append(" ");

          number = number % 10;

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      if (number <= 999)
      {
          builder.Append(numbers[firstDigit])
                 .Append(" hundred ");

          number = number % 100;

          if (number > 0)
          {
              builder.Append("and ");
          }

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      if (number <= 9999)
      {
          builder.Append(numbers[firstDigit])
                 .Append(" thousand ");

          number = number % 1000;

          AppendAndIfNeeded(number, builder);

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      if (number <= 19999)
      {
          int firstPart = firstDigit * 10 + (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[1]);

          builder.Append(numbers[firstPart])
                 .Append(" thousand ");

          number = number % 1000;

          AppendAndIfNeeded(number, builder);

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      if (number <= 99999)
      {
          int firstPart = firstDigit * 10 + (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[1]);

          ConvertToString(firstPart, builder);

          builder.Append(" thousand ");

          number = number % 1000;

          AppendAndIfNeeded(number, builder);

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      if (number <= 999999)
      {
          int firstPart = firstDigit * 100 + (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[1]) * 10 + (int)Char.GetNumericValue(digits[2]);

          ConvertToString(firstPart, builder);

          builder.Append(" thousand ");

          number = number % (firstPart * 1000);

          AppendAndIfNeeded(number, builder);

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      builder.Append("One million");
  }
  ```

  By using integer division instead of the calls of the numerous `(int)Char.GetNumericValue()` methods we can make the code more clear and can get rid of the `string digits` and as bonus we won't need to handle the edge cases anymore like so

  ```
  private static void ConvertToString(int number, StringBuilder builder)
  {
      if (number == 0) { return; }


      if (number <= 19)
      {
          builder.Append(numbers[number]);
          return;
      }

      if (number <= 99)
      {
          builder.Append(tens[number/10])
                 .Append(" ");

          number = number % 10;

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      if (number <= 999)
      {
          ConvertToString(number / 100, builder);

          builder.Append(" hundred ");

          number = number % 100;

          AppendAndIfNeeded(number, builder);

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      if (number <= 999999)
      {
          ConvertToString(number / 1000, builder);

          builder.Append(" thousand ");

          number = number % 1000;

          AppendAndIfNeeded(number / 1000, builder);

          ConvertToString(number, builder);
          return;
      }

      builder.Append("One million");
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and feel free to do so tomorrow as well. I will tick an answer after 72 hours since the time I posted this question.

Comment: For me the "tomorrow" is now ;-)

Comment: Hahahaha, okay okay. ;P

Answer (score 2):

**Design**

`NumberToWordsConverter` is a helper/utility class here, so it is best to make it a `static` class. That way you don't have to instantiate it before using it. It is not like you have various converters that will be used depending on the context like localized converters: English, French, Chinese...

```
public static class NumberToWordsConverter
{
    // I also marked them readonly since they are not meant to be changed.
    private static readonly string[] Numbers = { ... };
    private static readonly string[] Tens = { ... };

    public static string convertToString(int number) { ... }
}
```

**Naming Convention**

> DO use PascalCasing for all public member, type, and namespace names consisting of multiple words.

src : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public static string ConvertToString(int number)
```

**Defensively Coding**

While you validated the user input on the UI layer, `MainInterface` , it is also important to validate the argument passed on your business/service layer, `NumberToWordsConverter`.

```
public static string ConvertToString(int number)
{
    const int MinimumRange = 0, MaximumRange = 1000000;
    if (MinimumRange > number || number > MaximumRange)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("number", number,
            string.Format("Only number between {0} and {1}", MinimumRange, MaximumRange));
   // ...
}
```

**Negative Number**

```
public static string ConvertToString(int number);
```

[`int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx) is a pretty wide range, not only does it holds positive numbers up to 2,147,483,647, but also negative numbers down to -2,147,483,648. If we pass any negative number, the method simply returns `null`.

There is 3 ways of fixing it :

1. Throw an exception on negative numbers. This is covered in last section.
2. Change the parameter to `uint`.
3. Do a custom routine for negative numbers :

   ```
   public static string ConvertToString(int number)
   {
       if (number < 0)
           return "Minus " + ConvertToString(-number);

       // ...
   }
   ```

**Output**

> ```
> 90 Ninety 
> 91 Ninety One 
> 92 Ninety Two 
> 93 Ninety Three 
> 94 Ninety Four 
> 95 Ninety Five 
> 96 Ninety Six 
> 97 Ninety Seven 
> 98 Ninety Eight 
> 99 Ninety Nine 
> 100 One hundred 
> 101 One hundred and One 
> 102 One hundred and Two 
> 103 One hundred and Three 
> 104 One hundred and Four 
> 105 One hundred and Five 
> 106 One hundred and Six 
> 107 One hundred and Seven 
> 108 One hundred and Eight 
> 109 One hundred and Nine 
> 110 One hundred and Ten
> ```

I don't know if you have noticed the inconsistency. All units and tens are in title case, while the names of large number are in lower case. Consider making them all lower case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to show another way to spell numbers. It works like we think by dividing the whole number in sets of three digits and translating each into words. Finally it adds a thousands multiplier to each triplet if necessary. This is a generic method and can very easily be extended by just adding another thousands multiplier. It lacks range checking etc. but it's purpose is to just show another possible sollution.

Putting it in a sigle class might not be the best idea but here it is:

```
public static class NumberSpeller
{
    public static string SpellNumber(long number)
    {
        // parse digits and reverse their order
        var digits = number.ToString().Select(digit => int.Parse(digit.ToString())).Reverse().ToArray();

        var numberNames = new List<string>();

        // calc the number of triplets
        var tripletCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(digits.Length / 3.0);

        for (var tripletNumber = 0; tripletNumber < tripletCount; tripletNumber++)
        {
            var triplet = Triplet.ToText(digits, tripletNumber);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(triplet))
            {
                continue;
            }

            // add thousands multiplier if there is more then one triplet and we already have the first one
            if (tripletCount > 0 && tripletNumber > 0)
            {
                numberNames.Add(NumberNames.Triplets[tripletNumber]);
            }

            numberNames.Add(triplet);
        }

        // join all triplets
        var result = string.Join(" ", numberNames.AsEnumerable().Reverse());
        return result;
    }

    private class Triplet
    {
        private readonly int[] _digits;
        private readonly int _tripletNumber;

        private Triplet(int[] digits, int tripletNumber)
        {
            _digits = digits;
            _tripletNumber = tripletNumber;
        }

        private bool HasOnes { get { return Length >= 1; } }
        private bool HasTens { get { return Length >= 2; } }
        private bool HasHundreds { get { return Length == 3; } }

        private int Ones
        {
            get { return _digits[0]; }
        }

        private int Tens
        {
            get { return _digits[1]; }
        }

        private int Hundreds
        {
            get { return _digits[2]; }
        }

        public int Length
        {
            get { return _digits.Length; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var result = new List<string>();

            if (HasHundreds && Hundreds > 0)
            {
                // appent multiplier
                result.Add(NumberNames.Ones[Hundreds]);

                // append hundred
                result.Add(NumberNames.Triplets[0]);
            }

            if (HasTens && Tens > 0)
            {
                // tens are beetween 11 and 19
                if (Tens > 0 && Tens < 2)
                {
                    result.Add(NumberNames.Teens[Ones]);
                }
                // tens are greater then 19
                else if (Tens >= 2)
                {
                    result.Add(NumberNames.Tens[Tens - 2]);
                }
            }

            if (HasOnes)
            {
                // append zero only if there is one triplet and a single digit
                if (Ones == 0 && Length == 1 && _tripletNumber == 0)
                {
                    result.Add(NumberNames.Ones[Ones]);
                }
                else if (Length == 1 || (Length == 3 && Tens == 0 && Ones != 0))
                {
                    result.Add(NumberNames.Ones[Ones]);
                }
                else if (HasTens && Tens >= 2 && Ones > 0)
                {
                    result.Add(NumberNames.Ones[Ones]);
                }
            }
            return string.Join(" ", result);
        }

        // gets digits for a triplet
        private static int[] GetDigits(IReadOnlyCollection<int> digits, int tripletNumber)
        {
            var from = tripletNumber * 3;
            var to = tripletNumber * 3 + 2;

            var lastIndex = digits.Count - 1;

            if (from > lastIndex)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (to > lastIndex)
            {
                to = lastIndex;
            }

            var tripletDigits = digits.Where((digit, i) => i >= from && i <= to).ToArray();
            return tripletDigits;
        }

        public static string ToText(int[] digits, int tripletNumber)
        {
            var tripletDigits = GetDigits(digits, tripletNumber);
            var triplet = new Triplet(tripletDigits, tripletNumber);
            return triplet.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static class NumberNames
    {
        public static readonly string[] Ones =
        {
            "Zero",
            "One",
            "Two",
            "Three",
            "Four",
            "Five",
            "Six",
            "Seven",
            "Eight",
            "Nine",
        };

        public static readonly string[] Teens =
        {
            "Ten",
            "Eleven",
            "Twelve",
            "Thirteen",
            "Fourteen",
            "Fifteen",
            "Sixteen",
            "Seventeen",
            "Eighteen",
            "Nineteen"
        };

        public static readonly string[] Tens =
        {
            "Twenty",
            "Thirty",
            "Forty",
            "Fifty",
            "Sixty",
            "Seventy",
            "Eighty",
            "Ninety"
        };

        // this allows to easily extend the spellable number
        public static readonly string[] Triplets =
        {
            "Hundred",
            "Thousand",
            "Million",
            "Billion",
            "Trillion",
        };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numbers = new long[]
    {
        0,
        1,
        10,
        99,
        100,
        101,
        119,
        229,
        1001,
        1397,
        1000003,
        34345231,
        3100002201,
    };

    var texts = numbers.Select(n => n.ToString("N0") + " = " + NumberSpeller.SpellNumber(n));
    foreach (var text in texts)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(text);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }

    //Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Result:

```
0 = Zero
1 = One
10 = Ten
99 = Ninety Nine
100 = One Hundred
101 = One Hundred One
119 = One Hundred Nineteen
229 = Two Hundred Twenty Nine
1.001 = One Thousand One
1.397 = One Thousand Three Hundred Ninety Seven
1.000.003 = One Million Three
34.345.231 = Thirty Four Million Three Hundred Forty Five Thousand Two Hundred Thirty One
3.100.002.201 = Three Billion One Hundred Million Two Thousand Two Hundred One
```

Comment: Well, my example includes 'and' and stuff.